# An attempt to attach an auto-named database for file

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, dapper

I'm getting the following error when running my application:

> An attempt to attach an auto-named database for file
>   C:\Users\Bryan\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2015\Projects\app\app.UI\App_Data\aspnetdb.mdf failed. A database with
>   the same name exists, or specified file cannot be opened, or it is
>   located on UNC share.

Here is my connection string:

```
 <connectionStrings>
    <add name="SoundyDB" connectionString="data source=BRYAN\SQLEXPRESS;initial catalog=MusicKarma;User id = BRYAN\bryan; password=; MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=Soundy" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

I want to use SQL-server and my Database MusicKarma.

When I debug my application and inspect the connectionString-variable, It has the following value:

```
connectionString = "data source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|aspnetdb.mdf;User Instance=true"
```

I'm setting the connectionString variable this way:

```
public UserStore(string connectionString)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(connectionString))
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("Connectionstring");
    }
    this.connectionString = connectionString;
}

public UserStore()
{
    this.connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[0].ConnectionString;
}
```

Comment: Sorry for confusing. It seems you'd better to check that the code of ConfigurationManager has right value.

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace userStore method with the following:

```
public UserStore()
{
    this.connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SoundyDB"].ConnectionString;
}
```